# Update Running Total by summing every 3rd column

Tags: excel, sum

I am working on an excel workbook project and have run into a snag with trying to SUM in Column B for Products every 3rd column. We are tracking hours worked by our subcontractors on a daily basis and I am needing help with this. I am needing to take product totals from E5, H5, K5 and update B5 as values appear in future days to come. Any help on a formula for this would be awesome as I have been trying different versions of SUMIF and nested IF functions.

[image: Spread Sheet Display]

Comment: Why not `=SUMIF(E$3:XX$3,"Hours Worked",E5:XX5)` or something like that.

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you @BigBen . It has been about two years since I had to do my excel classes for my degree and excel has not been a program I have had to use the past two years. So thank you